# Why is the OpenTimeout option not being applied to New-PSSession?

Tags: powershell, powershell-remoting

In powershell I am trying to create a remote session. It fails (and that's ok, I know why it fails) but the issue is that I am trying to set a failure timeout.

**I create a New-PSSessionOption and set the OpenTimeout in milliseconds, but it seems that no matter what it always takes the same amount of time: 15 seconds.***

```
$cred = new-object -typename System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist $username, $password
$pso = New-PSSessionOption -OpenTimeout 10000
$server = "hostname"
$session = New-PSSession -ComputerName $server -Credential $cred -SessionOption $pso
...
Remove-PSSession $session
```

The error message which happens at the New-PSSession line, in case it is relevant to why the timeout isn't being applied, is this:

> Connecting to remote server "hostname" failed with the following error message : WinRM cannot complete the operation. Verify that the specified computer name is 
>   valid, that the computer is accessible over the network, and that a firewall exception for the WinRM service is enabled and allows access from this computer. By default, the WinRM firewall 
>   exception for public profiles limits access to remote computers within the same local subnet. For more information, see the about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help topic.

**Edit:** * When changing the OpenTimeout value it seems that it changes but stays within a certain range, 5-20 seconds. Perhaps there is an undocumented minimum and maximum for this parameter?